# jQuery event listener ignored on ng-view element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Okay so i have `<main id="page-content-wrapper" ng-view=""></main>` and I also have

```
$('#wrapper #page-content-wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("open");
});
```

This jQuery event listener is actually not listening. If i remove ng-view form this element it will be working. Of course it is simple to fix i just add another `div`. But i wonder what is causing it, probably all directives can cause similar problems.

Comment: I wonder, why do you want to use jquery click event in an angular app

Comment: share your idea we can help you achive your goal without jQuery

Comment: because i just started out with angular, and i heard i can use jQuery and angular alongside each other (i know there is jQlite).   i can as well solve this problem in angular but... can someone tell me why actually i can't use an event listener from jQuery on an element that has a directive on it? If i paste the code to chrome console it works fine after. It is like angular cuts the whole DOM part out for a while and insert it back. It doesn't work with `document.load` or `document.ready` either. Is there any workaround for this?